# Showing selected values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

am having problem, i want to select and each selected value displays
but when i select i only get one value from single box
and i dont want to use append because append keeps appending
even if i want to change select value it just appends and i want to select and other value show up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</form>

<div id="show_values"></div>

<script>
$('select').on('change', function (e) {

    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#show_values').text(txt+" ");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On a quick look, both `select` has same names. Try changing one so that it will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can get the selected values  using `children("option:selected")` of the select elements**

*Later we can store them in variables or display it in anywhere*

```js
$('select').on('change', function (e) {

    var txt = $('#a').children("option:selected").val();
    var txt2 = $('#b').children("option:selected").val();
    $('#show_values').text(txt+" "+txt2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="a">
      <option disabled selected value="">Please select value</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select name="cars2" id="b">
      <option disabled selected value="">Please select value</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>

<div id="show_values"></div>
```

Comment: yes thats it, but why on start selecting it brings to values if i sell audi bring audi but not audi and saab at same time

Comment: only output what is selected

Comment: its same as appending, choose 2 cars and see how many will output, its only 1. i need to select each select box and output the selected value

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var currentOption = $(this).children('option:selected').val()
    $('#show_values').text(currentOption);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</form>

<div id="show_values"></div>
```